# `python3 -m pipenv`, or just `pipenv`?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

There's too much going on with python dependency management/env management, I'm getting a little confused.

I saw a [blogpost](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) which convincingly argues for using `python3 -m pip`, instead of simply `pip3`. Does this apply to running `python3 -m pipenv` as well?

Since `pipenv` should manage the python version, do the concerns from the blogpost still apply? Or is it a best practice to run `python3 -m pipenv` just to be absolutely clear?

Answer (score 1):

*Since `pipenv` should manage the python version, do the concerns from the blogpost still apply? Or is it a best practice to run `python3 -m pipenv` just to be absolutely clear?*

[Pipenv page](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) show usage as `pipenv`, [basic-concepts chapter](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#basic-concepts) show that if you want explicitly express which version of `python` should be used then you might do
for python 3: `pipenv --three` and for python 2: `pipenv --two`

Comment: i guess i got confused since the Pipenv homepage also mentions `pip install --user pipenv`, whereas it seems the proper installation should be `python -m pip install --user pipenv`?